# In what line of sudoers do I put this?

Tags: sudo, visudo

```
%newgroup, !newuser ALL=(ALL:ALL)NOPASSWD:ALL, !/usr/sbin/iptables
```

I have read that it is put at the end, but I am not sure about it

[image]

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I want to make a new group less than one user of that group can execute any command through privilege elevation, except for the command that allows changing the firewall rules and without entering a password.

Comment: i wantto put that command on /etc/sudoers.tmp but i dont know exactlyt in which line

Comment: Which Ubuntu release you are using?

Comment: the version is 20.04.5

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-user-to-sudoers-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Note that allowing all *and* disallowing one command doesn't really work; any user can freely run `sudo /bin/bash` and happily run `iptables` from their shiny new root shell.

Answer (score 0):

Put a new line containing `%newgroup, !newuser ALL=(ALL:ALL)NOPASSWD:ALL, !/usr/sbin/iptables` at the end of `/etc/sudoers.tmp` after the line that contains this comment:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```